# Vuejs/Javascript How to differentiate between XML and JSON file provided in textarea?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, vue.js

I have a `textarea` in my `Vuejs` application to which users can upload the file from the local system. The upload file is either `XML` or `JSON`. I want to know how to add logic in my code to check if the uploaded file contents are `XML` or `JSON`.

Because for `JSON` file contents I need to run the command `JSON.stringify` after the upload, otherwise it would display as `[object][object]`. However, for `XML` file contents I do not need to run any command and directly load the contents to my `textarea`.

Can someone please help me how can I differentiate between the uploaded file contents `XML` and `JSON`?

Following is my code:

```
< input ref="fileDocument" type="file" hidden accept=".xml, .txt, .json" @change="readFile()">
< button class="btn btn-primary" @click="$refs.fileDocument.click()"> Upload File< /button>
```

My Vuejs code:

```
// Function to load the XML or JSON document file from local system
readFile () {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  this.file = this.$refs.fileDocument.files[0]
  this.$refs.fileDocument.value = null
  reader.onload = (res) => {
    res.target.value = res.target.result;
    //If JSON then perform JSON.stringify so file contents are not displayed as [object][object]
    this.inputFIle = JSON.stringify(res.target.result, undefined, '\t');
    
    //If XML then do not perform anything and directly load the contents to the textarea
    this.inputFile = res.target.result;
    
  }
  reader.onerror = (err) => {
    console.log("Error : " + err);
  }
  reader.readAsText(this.file)
},
```

As you can see after reading the file I need to make the decision based on the file content if the loaded file content is XML or JSON.

Following thigs tried:

1. I searched and found that I can run the `JSON.parse` to check if the input is `JSON` but the problem is that since I have it as `[object][object]`, `JSON.parse` would fail. Also, if I apply `JSON.stringify` on XML then it would add weird characters to my file contents. I have to run `JSON.parse` after running the `JSON.stringify` but in that case if the file content is `XML` then `JSON.stringify` would have added weird characters already.
2. I can check the file extension and make the decision if the content is XML or JSON but user might load the content in `txt` file so need to check that as well so I trying to figure out a way to find the content-type based on the file content itself rather than the file extension.

Comment: Shouldn't checking the very first character of the file be enough? A well formed XML file is supposed to start with a `<` while a well formed JSON file is supposed to start with a `{`

Comment: @secan — The first character of actual data in XML and JSON can be proceeded by as much white space as you like. The first character of data in JSON can be `{`, `[`,  `"`, `t`, `f`, `n`, or any number.

Comment: "If JSON then perform JSON.stringify so file contents are not displayed as [object][object]" — No! If it is JSON then it was probably created by using JSON.stringify in the first place. Don't confuse JavaScript data types with JSON.

Comment: @Quentin, I get your point but still, if the input can be either XML or JSON, if it is not XML (beginning with `<`) it is JSON. For what concerns the preceding white space(s), that can be easily handled with a regex, I think. So instead of checking the very first character, checking the first non white space character should still be a viable solution

Comment: @secan — Well yes, my point was that your approach needed refinement, not that it was completely in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Quentin, sorry maybe my intention was not clear: I did not take your comment as a bad criticism. Quite the opposite; as you were so kind to answer and amend some wrong presumptions (about  the format of JSON files), I considered it an opportunity to build on it and find a working solution for the problem. So, thank you :)

Comment: Given your code, I would assume `this.$refs.fileDocument.files[0]` to be a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). If so, you might get better results with trying to inspect [`File.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type). This said, you should spent some time revisting the docs for [`readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText). It states that your `res.target.result` will be the file contents as a string (as Quentin already noted). Meaning it's completely useless to `JSON.stringify` it.

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE:
in your example you are trying `JSON.stringify` on the response, so logically I assumed that it is an object (not stringified).
If they are both text, you can get them by the pattern as stated in above comments.

```js
if(res.target.result.includes('<')){
// do the xml stuff
} else {
// json stuff
}
```

if there is a risk that JSON string will contain `<` too, then you'll need to further upgrade the if

````
old answer
you can use `typeof()` where xml will return a string, and object or array will return array or object
```js
this.inputFile = typeof(res.target.result) === 'string' ? res.target.result : JSON.stringify(res.target.result)
````

Comment: The question is asking to differentiate XML and JSON, the type of either will be a string. You seem to have confused JSON with JavaScript.

Comment: I tried this approach but as mentioned in the above comment in both cases XML and JSON, I get the answer as `String` so this would not work for me.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008, I updated response based on your comment

Comment: Re edit: Here's a false positive for your XML test: `{ "not XML": "<<<<<<" }`

Comment: @Quentin, he said he has either XML or JSON. "<<<<<" this is not likely to be present in his api response. 
If the data is broken, or JSON contains "<", then he'll need to do more advanced checking. Somehting like regex check for valid json string:
`if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(text.replace(/\\["\\\/bfnrtu]/g, '@').
replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, '')))`

Comment: Following the conversation with Quentin, in the comments to the question, I think the condition should be `if (/^ *</.test(res.target.result)) { // is XML } else { // is JSON }` (instead of checking whether the value contains a `<` you verify that it *begins* with it - excluding white spaces)

Comment: @secan — You'd need `\s` rather than a literal space.